# Is there a way, using mod_rewrite, to remove both the .html AND the .php code from my website?

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

I'm wondering if there is a way, using mod_rewrite, to remove both the .html AND the .php code from my website?

Most of my pages are made with HTML, but the contact page, has the extention .php. Using the code in the .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

obviously takes care of the .html part of it. Is there to change this to include my one php page as well?

Or if nothing else, is there a way to write the mod_rewrite code out for each page individually, to get rid of their extentions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can double the RewriteRules and check for each possible extension (if a file with that name exists, then the rule will engage).

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html  -f
RewriteRule $  .html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php  -f
RewriteRule $  .php [NC,L]
```

The `$` regex just 'zero-width' matches the end of the current path, so the extension simply gets appended.

Least effort solution would be just using:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

(Enables a bit more server intelligence actually, but comes with slight performance cost.)

Answer (score 0):

If you've just a static site then probably you can use this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(my-contact-page-name)$ $1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

just make sure you enter `my-contact-page-name` without `.php` :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a totally different answer:

```
# Stop if static files:
RewriteRule (.*)(\.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico))$ - [NC,QSA,L]

# if it ends by htm or Php, 404:
RewriteRule (.*)(php|htm|html)$ - [L,R=404]

# if, when adding ".htm" it's a file...
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.htm  -f
# Rewrite it (and end processing):
RewriteRule (.*) $1.htm - [L,R=404]

# Same principles with "html" then php:
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html  -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html - [L,R=404]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php  -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php - [L,R=404]

# everything else = 404:
RewriteRule . - [L,R=404]
```

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

May I ask you to add the rewritelog in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This will get rid of the extensions but will redirect to one page: index.php
In which you can check if the page exists and include it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [NC,L]
```